# Rolling Dice Histogram Not Giving The Supposed Output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, histogram

So here's my code:
You can see the code down below:

```
import random
from collections import defaultdict

def main():
    dice = 11
    sides = 6
    rolls = 1000
    result = roll(dice, sides, rolls)
    maxH = 0
    for i in range(dice, dice * sides + 1):
        if result[i] / rolls > maxH: maxH = result[i] / rolls
    for i in range(dice, dice * sides + 1):
        print('{:2d}{:10d} {}'.format(i, result[i], '*' * int(result[i] / rolls / maxH * 40)))


def roll(dice, sides, rolls):
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for _ in range(rolls):
        d[sum(random.randint(1, sides) for _ in range(dice))] += 1
    return d

main()
```

And the output that I want is:

```
11:
12:
13:
14:
15:
16:
17:
18: *
19: ****
20:
21: ***
22: ******
23: ********
24: ****************
25: *************
26: **********
27: *********************************
28: ****************************************
29: *********************************
30: ***************************************************
31: *****************************************************************
32: ********************************************************
33: **************************************************************************************
34: ***********************************************************
35: *********************************************************************
36: ***********************************************************************************
37: **************************************************************
38: *****************************************************************
39: ***************************************
40: *****************************************************
41: ************************************ 
42: ****************************
43: ************************
44: ************************
45: *********
46: ***********
47: *******
48: ***
49: **
50:
51:
52: *
53:
54:
55:
56:
57:
58:
59:
60:
61:
62:
63:
64:
65:
66:
```

But for some reason it's not giving me this exact output.What's the problem, can't find  a solution ?
(Note: The question of this code was this: **"Write a program that takes an integer argument n, and rolls 11 fair six-sided dice, n times. Use an integer
array to tabulate the number of times each possible total (between 11 and 66) occurs. Then print a text
histogram of the results, as illustrated below. (You can take n as 1000)."**)

Comment: As I understand, you don't want to write the count next to each bar? This prints only sum and the bar: `print('{:2d}: {}'.format(i, '*' * int(result[i] / rolls / maxH * 80)))`

Comment: @AndrejKesely well for the 18th line for example, in my code the output is " " but for the supposed result it's " * ". Not having the same amount of * per line is my problem :/

Comment: You can compute `maxH = max(result.values())`  and then do `print('{:2d}: {}'.format(i, '*' * int(result[i] / maxH * 100)))` Then the * at 18th index will show (but not all the times)

Comment: @AndrejKesely the thing that makes me confused is this , how can I compute the exact same output if I'm rolling dice? I mean it's random how's that even possible in the first place ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Exact same output is difficult with random numbers, but look at `random.seed()`. If you initialize random generator to some exact value, then the output will be the same all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print('{:2d}: {}'.format(i, '*' * int(result[i] / rolls / maxH * 80)))

maxH = max(result.values())
```

and then do

```
print('{:2d}: {}'.format(i, '*' * int(result[i] / maxH * 100)))
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but where do I have to put these lines exactly? I tried to replace these codes with the old ones but still it's not the same.